# Add ExternalLink column to DefaultDataTable in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a `DefaultDataTable` to display entities and in one of its columns I'd like to have links (`ExternalLink`) for those entities. But doing the following does not really give me links, it shows only the link text.

This way I create the columns:

```java
List<IColumn<Entity, String>> columns = List.of(
  new PropertyColumn<>(new Model<>("Id"), "id", "id"),
  new PropertyColumn<>(new Model<>("Name"), "name", "name"),
  new IColumn<>() {
    @Override
    public Component getHeader(String componentId) {
      return new Label(componentId, "Link");
    }
    @Override
    public String getSortProperty() {
      return null; // No sorting
    }
    @Override
    public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<Entity>> cellItem, String componentId, IModel<Entity rowModel) {
      cellItem.add(new ExternalLink(componentId,
        "https://example.com/entity/" + rowModel.getObject().getExtid()),
        rowModel.getObject().getName());
    }
    @Override
    public void detach() { }
  }
);
```

This way the DefaultDataTable is created:

```java
var entityDataTable = new DefaultDataTable<>("entity_data_table", columns, dataProvider, 20);
add(entityDataTable);
```

But in the browser it looks like the second column is just repeated as the third:

[image]

So how can I show a link column in a data table? Btw. I'm using Apache Wicket 9.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide markup for the cell contents. I.e. instead of adding an ExternalLink you need to add a markup provider like a `Panel` or a `Fragment` that contains the ExternalLink as a child.

```
@Override
public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<Entity>> cellItem, String componentId, IModel<Entity rowModel) {
  cellItem.add(new MyPanel(componentId));
}
...
```

MyPanel.java:

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {
  public MyPanel(String id) {
    super(id);

    add(new ExternalLink("link",
    "https://example.com/entity/" + rowModel.getObject().getExtid()),
    rowModel.getObject().getName()));
  }
}
```

MyPanel.html:

```
<wicket:panel><div><a wicket:id="link"></a></div></wicket:panel>
```

Comment: Cool stuff, thanks. I had to add `<wicket:panel>` around the `div` in your provided `MyPanel.html` to make it work in the end, thanks to the verbose error message :)